# When a function of bounded variation is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I came across a question: let $f(x)$ be a function of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ which has a primitive, then $f(x)$ is continous. I don't know how to prove it. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the one-sided limits of $f$ always exist since $f$ is the difference of two non-decreasing functions. Since derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property we must have that these limits must in fact be equal.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I still cannot figure it out. For example, why must these limits be equal? And even if they are equal, why is the function continuous? Could you please explain further?

Comment: For your first question: Assume $\lim_{x\to y^-}f(x)=a<b=\lim_{x\to y^+} f(x)$. Could you have a point $z_r\in(y-r,y+r)$ such that $f(z_r)=(a+b)/2$ for every $r>0$? Think of the definition of limit.

Comment: Another question:Can $f$ be the difference of two non-decreasing functions which both have primitives?

Comment: @ksj03: Could that happen? Yes. Could we deduce this from the fact that $f$ has a primitive? No.

Comment: But It seems that you have used the fact in your argument. Otherwise how can we get the one-sided limits and then evoke the Darboux's theorem.

Comment: The existence of the one-sided limits always holds for any $BV$ function. Darboux theorem is applied directly to $f$, I never claimed that the increasing functions had a primitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20963/discussion-between-ksj03-and-jose27).